# Tumblr Photoset zoom problem on Chrome and Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, html, css, tumblr

I've seen many posts discussing photoset problems on Tumblr but none mine. Visit [JessPaul.net](http://JessPaul.net) for reference.

My single photo posts open in a separate lightbox when clicked. GREAT!:
[single photo in new page lightbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8ToY.jpg)

With my multi-photosets, however, you can click on an image, but instead of opening in a new tab, it zooms the picture in maybe 300% and hides most of the pic inside the iframe.

[the photoset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9PXLP.jpg)
Clicking picture on the far right:
[clicking far right pic in the photoset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozJsE.jpg)

I actually do not have any {photoset} code built into my customized Tumblr theme. I tried a bunch from previous Tumblr/photoset code suggestions from stackoverflow, but none of them fixed this problem.

Here is simply what my photo code look like:

```
.photo {width: 600px;}


 {block:Photo}
                            <div class="photo">     
                              {LinkOpenTag}<img alt="{PhotoAlt}" src="{PhotoURL-500}"/>{LinkCloseTag}
                              {block:Caption}{Caption}{/block:Caption}
                              {block:Date}
                                  <div class="info"><a href="{Permalink}">{MonthNumberWithZero}/{DayOfMonth}/{ShortYear}</a>
                                  </div>
                              {/block:Date}
                            </div>
                        {/block:Photo}
```

**BIG NOTE**: This is happening on Chrome and Internet Explorer but not Firefox. On Firefox, it separates the photo from the photoset like the other browsers do but only zooms it to about 500px or the edge of the iframe like:

[clicking into photoset on Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hcwoe.jpg)

I don't know if this is a browser-automated problem? I like everything about my photoset layout except for this hyperlinked-zoom problem. I will take either the Firefox edge-of-iframe zoom or the lightbox for the individual photos in the photoset. I'll even take no hyperlink into the photos in the photoset, but the zoom in the iframe is obviously pretty useless.